# Error: libfreetype.6.dylib requires version 54.0.0 or later, but libpng16.16.dylib provides version 52.0.0

Tags: python, compiler-errors, executable, lib

I compiled an executable of a python script using pyinstaller, but when I try to run my executable I get the error "libfreetype.6.dylib requires version 54.0.0 or later, but libpng16.16.dylib provides version 52.0.0." I feel like I need to update libpng16.16.dylib or libfreetype.6.dylib, but am not sure how to do that. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I have this same problem. Very difficult to solve. I have tried manually including the correct (home-brew) dynamic libraries as "binaries" in the .spec file, and even tried tricking pyinstaller by symlinking the correct files. When I execute the compiled file on my Mac, it works, but on any other Mac it fails with this same error.